# How do you specify the html5 doctype with Python Chameleon?

Tags: python, chameleon, template-metal

I've thoroughly RTFMed and Googled for this, and I can't seem to find the answer. I am new to Chameleon, so maybe it's just so obvious that it's no where to be found, but when I put

`<!DOCTYPE html>`

in my master template, the rendered page has it stripped out resulting in the dreaded quirksmode.

Is there a trick that I'm missing?

Comment: If you use a whole file as the macro (`use-macro="load: master.pt"`) this won't be a problem. Anyway, you should create an answer for this so that it be considered answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. You need to wrap the entire master template in a metal tag like so: `<metal:macro metal:define-macro="layout"> <!DOCTYPE html> ... </html></metal:macro>`